# Replace part of string for messy data (faster way instead of string replace)?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, fasttext

I want to replace the many values of product variants.

```
Big Ben Personalized Products AVENGERS – Stark / 2 set                                                2
BigBen Personalized Products Expendables – Statham / 2 set                                            2
BigBen Personalized Toy 20.00% Off Auto renew Adults Toy / 5 set                                      2
BigBen Personalized Toy 20.00% Off Auto renew Adults Toy / 3 set                                       1
Personalized Toy 5 set                                                                                  1
BIG BEN Personalized  Machine 20.00% Off Auto renew (Versand jeden 3 Monate) Kids Toy / 3 set    1
BigBen Personalized Toy 20.00% Off Auto renew (Versand jeden 2 Monate) Kids Toy / 5 set            1
BigBen Personalized Toy 20.00% Off Auto renew (Versand jeden 2 Monate) Adults Toy / 5 set              1
BigBen Personalized Products 20.00% Off Auto renew (Versand jeden 5 Monate) Adults Toy / 5 set
```

There are many product variants that actually carry the same values.

I want to know whether there is a faster way than using:

```
df["product_variant"]= df["product_variant"].str.replace('BigBen Personalized', '',case = False) 
df["product_variant"]= df["product_variant"].str.replace('Big Ben Personalized ', '',case = False)
df["product_variant"]= df["product_variant"].str.replace('BigBen Personalized', '',case = False)
df["product_variant"]= df["product_variant"].str.replace('Auto renew', '',case = False)
```

```
I expect the data row by row to look more like this:
AVENGERS - Stark (2 set)
Expendables - Statham (2 set)
Adults Toy (5 set)
Toy (5 set)
Kids Toy (3 set)
Kids Toy (5 set)
Adults Toy (5 set)
Kids Toy (5 set)
Adults Toy (3 set)
```

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a specific pattern with 2 capturing groups for those examples.

For most items, first match all until after `Products` or before either `Adults` or `Kids`

- Capture in **group 1** the part before the `/` if it is present.
- Capture in **group 2** 1 or digits followed by `set`

Example pattern

```
^(?:big\s*ben personalized (?:products\s+)?(?:.*?(?=Adult|Kids))?|personalized\s+)(\w+(?: \w+)*(?: – \w+(?: \w+)*)?)(?: /)? (\d+ set)\b.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7OMsay/1)

In the replacement using the 2 capturing groups `\1 (\2)`

```
import pandas as pd

regex = r"^Event:\s+Task_(\d+)Error:(NO_ERROR|ERROR_(?:MINOR|\d+))(?:\w+:(\w+))?"

items = [
    "Big Ben Personalized Products AVENGERS – Stark / 2 set                                                2",
    "BigBen Personalized Products Expendables – Statham / 2 set                                            2",
    "BigBen Personalized Toy 20.00% Off Auto renew Adults Toy / 5 set                                      2",
    "BigBen Personalized Toy 20.00% Off Auto renew Adults Toy / 3 set                                       1",
    "Personalized Toy 5 set                                                                                  1",
    "BIG BEN Personalized  Machine 20.00% Off Auto renew (Versand jeden 3 Monate) Kids Toy / 3 set    1",
    "BigBen Personalized Toy 20.00% Off Auto renew (Versand jeden 2 Monate) Kids Toy / 5 set            1",
    "BigBen Personalized Toy 20.00% Off Auto renew (Versand jeden 2 Monate) Adults Toy / 5 set              1",
    "BigBen Personalized Products 20.00% Off Auto renew (Versand jeden 5 Monate) Adults Toy / 5 set                   "
]


df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=["product_variant"])
df["product_variant"] = df["product_variant"].replace(
    r'(?i)^(?:big\s*ben personalized (?:products\s+)?(?:.*?(?=Adult|Kids))?|personalized\s+)(\w+(?: \w+)*(?: – \w+(?: \w+)*)?)(?: /)? (\d+ set)\b.*',
    r'\1 (\2)',
    regex=True
)
print(df)
```

Output

```
                 product_variant
0       AVENGERS – Stark (2 set)
1  Expendables – Statham (2 set)
2             Adults Toy (5 set)
3             Adults Toy (3 set)
4                    Toy (5 set)
5               Kids Toy (3 set)
6               Kids Toy (5 set)
7             Adults Toy (5 set)
8             Adults Toy (5 set)
```